# What's a good website for logging cycling trip data?

Tags: equipment

Whenever I go cycling I reset my bike computer (measures distance, speed, time, and various statistics based on these quantities, such as average speed) and set up my Polar training computer (measures heart rate, time, and various statistics based on these quantities, such as average heart rate).

When I get back I log basic statistics---date, duration, route, average speed, max speed, heart rate info, and a short description---into an HTML file that has gotten rather large.

I've been wondering whether there's a site, with nice user interface, that would allow me to log these data online? Ideally one would be able to see the aggregate distance and aggregate duration within various time periods, etc.; it would also be good to be able to log routes on a Google maps-like map which one could then share with others.

I realize this question is only tangentially related to cycling; still, this seems to be a relevant place to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Strava](https://www.strava.com/) is the de facto standard these days.

Has some nice social features, like segments where your times are compared against others, friends and messages.

[Training Peaks](http://home.trainingpeaks.com/) is more of a training log than a social platform, has some nice features for planning and talking to a coach.

[Polar](https://www.polarpersonaltrainer.com/), [Garmin](https://connect.garmin.com/), etc. have their own home made solutions. I've not personally used the Polar one, but Garmin Connect always feels half finished, I only use it to sync to Strava and Training Peaks.

And of course, there are a [million others](https://www.cyclinganalytics.com/), but I think these are the biggest options.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out. I've tried Polar but I don't like it.